# How to disable JTable sorting when altering the TableModel?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablerowsorter

So I have a JTable filled with many elements and a TableRowSorter to sort the rows. This table has a "pulling" mode that checks for any changes from an outside source and updates the TableModel as necessary.

The problem is that the sorting causes the Table to flicker when the table is refreshing its contents. How can I make it so that the JTable does draw to screen until 1) the contents have been refreshed 2) these contents have been sorted?

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example? How do you update the table? Do you replace the model or update it's contents? What events do you trigger?

Comment: Where is your `SSCCE`? You have been asked before to post a SSCCE with your question so you we understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (this is what happens if you do not provide a `SSCCE`) you have a table model based on `DefaultTableModel` and adding the new contents in some sort of a loop using `addRow`. Each call to `addRow` in-turn invokes `fireTableRowsInserted`. This is caught by the UI and the table is refreshed.

What you need to do is avoid the firing the event till all the rows are inserted. Override the `insertRow` method from the model and remove the fire event. You can fire the event after all the rows are inserted.